# Python flask audio stream weird results

Tags: python, numpy, flask, web, audio

The Flask function to return the chunks of audio sometimes works sometimes it doesn't and sometimes the duration in the audio tag appears buggy as well

```py
@bp.route('/api/music/<string:filename>')
def get_music_file(filename: str):
    wav_header = genHeader(44100, 16, 2)
    instance_path = current_app.config["UPLOAD_DIRECTORY"]
    file_path = os.path.join(instance_path, filename)
    print(file_path)
    def generate():
        if (os.path.exists(file_path)):
            print(f'\n\n{file_path}\n\n')

        else:
            print('\n\nDoesnt exist\n\n')
        frequency, signal = wavfile.read(file_path)

        print(f'\n\n{frequency}\n\n\n')
        slice_length = 1
        overlap = 0
        slices = np.arange(0, len(signal)/frequency, slice_length - overlap, np.int64)

        for start, end in zip(slices[:-1], slices[1:]):
            start_audio = start * frequency
            end_audio = (end + overlap) * frequency
            audio_slice = signal[int(start_audio) : int(end_audio)]

            import io

            bytes_wav = bytes()
            byte_io = io.BytesIO(bytes_wav)
            wavfile.write(byte_io, 44100, audio_slice)
            yield wav_header + byte_io.read()

    return current_app.response_class(generate(), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
```

the complete code can be found at: [github repo](https://github.com/HeitorRaimundoPrado/reactjs-remote-video-player/tree/sound)

Tried to change headers, used diferent functions to generate np.array like audio2numpy, but nothing changed the bugs

Comment: It appears I had forgotten to account for sample size on the header, but still when the client fetches from the server for some reason the <audio> tag displays twice the real length of the audio